# Null space of linear map is the orthogonal complement to the range.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

If $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n} $, is it true that null$(A) = (\text{range} (A))^{\perp} $. Or is it only true if $A = A^{T}$?

Comment: Consider say a projection onto a codimension-1 subspace along a non-orthogonal vector. If you work over the reals ($\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard inner product) you should be able to visualise examples.

Comment: If $\perp$ is defined relative to the usual inner product over $\Bbb C^{n}$, then this statement does **not** necessarily hold if $A = A^T$ (where $A^T$ denotes the transpose as opposed to the conjugate-transpose).